# Adding openssh package to alpine docker

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, openssh, alpine-package-keeper

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache curl openssh sshpass rsync
#etc
```

And this docker-compose.yml:

```
[...]
services:
  my-container:
    build:
      context: ./my-folder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: my-container
    restart: unless-stopped
    #etc
```

And I'm running this command:

```
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans --build
```

I'm getting this error on build:

```
 => ERROR [3/7] RUN apk add --no-cache curl openssh sshpass rsync                                                                                                                                               3.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 > [3/7] RUN apk add --no-cache curl openssh sshpass rsync:                                                                                                                                                          
#0 1.448 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                              
#0 1.859 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                         
#0 2.732 ERROR: unable to select packages:                                                                                                                                                                           
#0 2.741   openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3:
#0 2.741     breaks: openssh-client-default-9.3_p2-r0[openssh-client-common=9.3_p2-r0]
```

And for the life of me I cannot figure this out. I tried changing the the alpine image version to a few other options, I ran `docker builder prune` just in case this was some kind of caching problem. I also tried forcing specific versions numbers for openssh and running just with `RUN apk add --no-cache openssh`, but the error still appeared.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: answers to comments.

Docker is running on Raspberry Pi OS (64 bit), fully updated.

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.4
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.5
 Git commit:        3713ee1
 Built:             Fri Jul  7 14:50:52 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.4
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.5
  Git commit:       4ffc614
  Built:            Fri Jul  7 14:50:52 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: What application will the container ultimately run?  How does it invoke `ssh`?  Can you use a library for it instead of calling a subprocess?

Comment: When I try to build it, it installs without error. The only thing I can think of that might cause different behaviour is the hardware platform. I'm on x86_64. What are you on?

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce this problem. Can you tell us more about your environment? Host OS, docker version, etc. What is the output of `docker image ls alpine`?

Comment: @DavidMaze container runs a .sh script that runs rsync which uses ssh. I don't understand what you mean with "library instead of subprocess", but using rsync seems pretty standard, so I'd like to keep using the .sh script exactly as I have it (not to mention that the script has been tested already and I'd be a pain to change it).

Comment: @larsks Output of "docker image ls alpine" is an empty list.

Comment: I only have 32 bit raspberry pi os, and this all works fine in that environment (using the same version of docker).

Comment: @larsks To be fair, this has worked flawlessly for many months, and so it's also a surprise for me that it stopped working out of the blue a few days ago.

Comment: My guess is that there is an issue with the apk packages for arm64. But as I don't have access to an arm64 machine, I don't have any way to verify.

Answer (score 4):

We got the same issue for the last week or so on our gitlab pipelines running on on-demand aws t2.Large instances running scripts in `docker:git` containers (Runtime platform arch=amd64 os=linux revision=79704081 version=16.0.1).

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: docker:git
    services: 
        - docker:dind
    before_script:
        - apk update
        - apk add openssh gettext ca-certificates
```

Resulting in:

> $ apk add openssh gettext ca-certificates
> ERROR: unable to select packages:
> openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3:
> breaks: openssh-client-default-9.3_p2-r0[openssh-client-common=9.3_p2-r0]

The fix was to remove the `openssh` from `apk add`

I think the issue was related to this Alpine [release](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.15.9-3.16.6-3.17.4-3.18.2-released.html) with a security fix for OpenSSH. Noticing that `openssh-client-default` is already in Alpine, and is conflicting with the version that we are trying to add, made us realize that we can just remove the `add`.

Comment: Ah I see! Actually, I also found out that the alpine:edge version (instead of alpine:latest) does not produce the error, so I've been using that since yesterday. But I will try your option too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `openssh-client` (and it's dependency `openssh-client-common`) that is installed in an image is older then the one in package repository. When you are trying to install a newer openssh server package, the conflict with older common packages occurs. I think upgrading the packages on the image should fix the issue:

```
RUN apk update && apk --no-cache upgrade
# or, for smaller impact:
RUN apk update && apk --no-cache upgrade openssh-client
```

Or you can wait for newer alpine version to be released (should work already).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR The `docker>=24.0.5` is able to install openssh properly.

```
docker run --rm -it docker:24.0.2 /bin/sh
# apk add openssh
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3:
    breaks: openssh-client-default-9.3_p2-r0[openssh-client-common=9.3_p2-r0]

docker run --rm -it docker:24.0.3 /bin/sh
# apk add openssh
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3:
    breaks: openssh-client-default-9.3_p2-r0[openssh-client-common=9.3_p2-r0]

docker run --rm -it docker:24.0.4 /bin/sh
# apk add openssh
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3:
    breaks: openssh-client-default-9.3_p2-r0[openssh-client-common=9.3_p2-r0]

docker run --rm -it docker:24.0.5 /bin/sh
# apk add openssh
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing openssh-sftp-server (9.3_p2-r0)
(2/4) Installing openssh-server-common (9.3_p2-r0)
(3/4) Installing openssh-server (9.3_p2-r0)
(4/4) Installing openssh (9.3_p2-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r2.trigger
OK: 33 MiB in 59 packages
```

I also checked the pkgs of alpine:3.18 and the `openssh-client-common-9.3_p1-r3` package is no longer exists.

It turns out the OpenSSH before 9.3p2 has impacted by `CVE-2023-38408`.
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-38408

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).